# Comparing key and values of two java maps

Tags: java, dictionary, comparison

I'm still relatively new to Java and I'm finding myself stuck on trying to properly write this piece of code that I feel should be a bit more simple.

I have two maps made up of two different instances of the same object.  The keys are objects, and the values are objects.

There are two instances because I'm trying to determine if the keys in one instance are different from the keys in another instance.  I'm trying to specifically locate new keys or missing keys, and then compare the values of the keys which exist in both maps.

The sample code below is just to help visualize what I'm trying to do (hopefully it's not more confusing!)

The goal of the below example should tell me that key "C" is missing and there is a new key ("D") and then it should finally compare the values of keys in both maps.

Main question is, is there anyway to do this in one loop?  Primarily because my actual code will touch the file system for the values in the map and I'm trying to minimize the times it has to touch the disk

```
Map<objA, objB> mapA = new HashMap<objA, objB>();
mapA.put("A", "1");
mapA.put("B", "2");
mapA.put("C", "3");

Map<objA, objB> mapB = new HashMap<objA, objB>();
mapB.put("A", "1");
mapB.put("D", "4");

// Check if something is missing from mapB
for(Map.Entry<objA, objB> entryMapA:mapA.entrySet())
{
    if(!mapB.containsKey(entryMapA.getKey())
        {
            System.out.println(entryMapA.getKey() + " is missing");
        }
}

// Check if something is new is in mapB
for(Map.Entry<objA, objB> entryMapB:mapB.entrySet())
{
    if(!mapA.containsKey(entryMapB.getKey())
    {  
        System.out.println(entryMapB.getKey() + " is new");
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds exactly like [Guava's `Maps.difference`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#difference(java.util.Map,%20java.util.Map)).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Keys in a `Map` are `Set`s, so you can use sets and the available operations on them.

For instance:

```
Set<String> keysInA = new HashSet<String>(mapA.keySet());
Set<String> keysInB = new HashSet<String>(mapB.keySet());

// Keys in A and not in B
Set<String> inANotB = new HashSet<String>(keysInA);
inANotB.removeAll(keysInB);

// Keys common to both maps
Set<String> commonKeys = new HashSet<String>(keysInA);
commonKeys.retainAll(keysInB);
```

etc etc.

Note: you MUST NOT use the key set of a map directly. If you do:

```
// This returns the actual key set of the map, NOT a copy!
Set<String> inANotB = mapA.keysSet();
inANotB.removeAll(mapB.keySet())
```

you actually *remove the keys (and their associated values) in `mapA`*.

Finally, you should note that `HashSet` makes no order guarantee. If this matters to you, you want to look at implementations of `SortedSet` (such as `TreeSet`).

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but I don't understand when you say "you MUST NOT use the key set of a map directly: it is mutable."  I'm still new to programming so some of the terms are confusing... what is mutable?

Comment: @nkon: the `Set` returned by `.keySet()` is the actual set of keys of the map. If you modify that set, you modify the map itself. And you probably do not want that ;)

Comment: @fge: It's true you need a copy if you want to perform destructive modifications on the sets without changing the original map, but there's no need to make **two** copies of each as your code does. (I realize you do this so each variable is its own copy.) This is an example of where a functional style (pure functions that return new copies instead of mutator methods), like the Guava utilities that Louis mentions in the comment above, lead to clearer code.

Comment: @DanielPryden yeah, I use Guava a lot, but does the OP use it? If it were me, all of Guava should be in the JDK proper (and so would Joda Time), but who am I to decide? ;)

Comment: I've heard of Guava before, but to very honest, I'm extremely new to programming and to Java, so I wouldn't even know how to use Guava since it doesn't appear to be a part of the standard API.

Answer (score 1):

You may subtract the the keysets:

```
Set<objA> keysA1 = new HashSet<objA>(mapA.keySet()); // deepcopy
Set<objA> keysA2 = new HashSet<objA>(mapA.keySet()); // deepcopy
Set<objB> keysB = new HashSet<objB>(mapB.keySet()); // deepcopy

keysA1.removeAll(keysB);
keysB.removeAll(keysA2);

System.out.println("Missing in A: " + keysB);
System.out.println("Missing in B: " + keysA1);
```

Comment: Almost +1, but your `// deepcopy` comments are misleading at best. The `HashSet` constructor only makes a **shallow** copy. You get away with it here because strings are immutable, but if you had mutable objects in the sets then those instances would be shared between the copies.